# sed operation need to append text between some tags

Tags: linux, ant

Need to append text between tag e.g.  { text here }

```
sed -i -e 's/<\/Directory>/Hello/g' text.txt
```

But this replace <\Directory> and everywhere.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you want to replace only the word `Directory` with `Hello`?

Comment: So, @Samarth, I need to add my text '' Hello'  after <\Directory> tag and once

Answer (score 1):

To append Hello at the first occurence of /Directory do:

```
sed -i -e '0,/<\/Directory>/s//<\/Directory>Hello/' text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the part you don't want deleted:

`sed -i -e 's/<\/Directory>/<\/Directory>Hello/g' text.txt`

Comment: So, this is work partly. Now the <\Directory> is not removed and my new text 'Hello' was appended. But now I need to append it only once. Thanks

Comment: Where do you need to append it? at the first occurence? Or some other place special?

Comment: at first occurency